# ansi escape sequences not working in windows cmd prompt

Tags: c, linux, ansi-escape

I tried the ANSI escape sequences like `\033[K \033[%dd \033[%dG` etc, in AIX.
When I used telnet in windows, it didn't work.
The same is working fine using putty.

I don't want to use NCURSES, but `printf`s. Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: I just realised I'm not sure that my answer is on the money. Telnet to what? PuTTY is a program; what protocol did you use? And, again, connecting to what? Ultimately, something like NCURSES is the right solution here: why don't you want to use it?

Comment: Accept some previous answers please, and you do not need to sign greetings in your questions as SO is not a forum.

Answer (score 5):

Windows's command-prompt is not ANSI.

It has its own set of commands to use, but they are not escape sequences.

You can, however, use [`ANSI.SYS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI.SYS) to gain access to similar functionality.

Read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Windows_and_DOS).

Comment: I tried modifying the ANSI.SYS. As mentioned by microsoft, we need to specify dosonly in CONFIG.NT. But in command.com, telnet is not working. And without DOSONLY, the escape sequences are not working even after including the ANSI.SYS entry.